# Run asynchronous task in OnReceive() method of broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I want to run async task in onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) method. now i want to use context of OnReceive....because i have to use  :  Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(); for getting the cursor so its throwing null pointer exception if I use context defined globally..so how to take context of Onreceive() method for running it asynch task inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a global `Context` in the `BroadCastReceiver` and assign the `Context` instance inside the `onReceive()` to this global Context instance and use it,

```
Context context;

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        this.context = arg0;
            // now use context instance in your AsyncTask class.
        }
```

Comment: hi Lalit poptani ...it it compulsorily to use Intent arg1 in side OnReceive()  ?

Comment: No, its used when any Intent being received.

Comment: lalit one more question   in on post execute i am running other method for sending email  using                 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), ACTIVITY_CREATE);
but there is error in ACTIVITY_CREATE ...now what should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223556/send-mail-function-inside-onpostexecute-in-broadcast-receiver  pls refer to this link...thnks

Comment: hi lalit i am waiting for ur response ..pls see above link thakns]